# Click in a button

Tags: vba, dom

How do I write the code to click in that button "Catálogo"?

Button and HTML Code Image:

[image]

My code so far:

```
'This will load a webpage in IE
Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE.Visible = True

'Define URL
URL = "https://www.wix.com/my-account/sites/0761466b-a270-4ab2-a3b3-e7498df11329/app/1380b703-ce81-ff05-f115-39571d94dfcd?referralInfo=DA_Wix%20Stores"

'Navigate to URL
IE.navigate URL

' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...
'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

'Webpage Loaded
Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

'Unload IE
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

'Click on desired button
With IE.document
    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("  ")
            elems.Click
End With
```

The tag name is blank because I tried lots of things and none of them worked.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know what to pass into `getElementsByTagName`? Or something else? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant element is not actually a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) or an [`<input type=button/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-type), but rather an [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element, or *anchor element*.

Keep in mind that `getElementsByTagName` will return all the `a` elements in the page; you probably only want a specific element.

If you have IE11 installed, you can call [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), passing in a CSS selector:

```
With IE.document
    Dim elem As Object
    Set elem = .querySelector("#etpa-iframe > html > body > store-manager > div > side-bar > div > navigation > ul")
    elem.click
End With
```

---

If you want to select the second `li` under the `navigation`, you can use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector:

```
Set elem = .querySelector("#etpa-iframe > html > body > store-manager > div > side-bar > div > navigation > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a")
```

Comment: It returns error "424" - Object required, do you know why?
I noticed it has a #document right before html tag, and also it must finish at the first tag a, which is inside the second tag li, which is inside the ul as you mentioned, so the code would continue as ...navigation > ul > li > a. How do i mention this position? I tried combinations of .queryselectorall(" ")(i), but didn't work.

Thank you for your help Zev Spitz.

Comment: @RafaelCosta Updated.