# Click button on login page

Tags: vba

I'm trying to automate the login at www.tdameritrade.com and am able to fill out the username and password using:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("userid").Value = "username"
IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "password"
```

The login button doesn't have an Id.

How can I click the button when the code for it is:

```
<button tabindex="5" title="Log in" class="main-header-login-submit btn btn-green-solid" type="submit" href="https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/login" value="Log in" target="_self"></button>
```

Comment: do any of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262485/click-in-a-button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153744/use-excel-vba-to-click-on-a-button-in-internet-explorer-when-the-button-has-no https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670379/excel-vba-ie-clicking-a-button

Comment: Is the button part of a form?

Comment: use `GetElementsByClassName` and iterate that collection with additional logic if needed, there's probably only one item that matches that query, but if there's more than one, you need to figure out which one to "click".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim divClassLogin As Object

IE.Document.getElementById("userid").Value = "username"
IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "password"

Set divClassLogin = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("main-header-login-fields")

divClassLogin(0).Children(2).Click
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for the Children(2) please ? I guess it DOM model but how does that fit with what is shown in the question? Genuine question.

Comment: If you look at the source code on td ameritrade home page, and find the div element with class name "main-header-login-fields", you will see that it contains 3 children elements: 2 inputs and 1 button. Children(2) refers to the login button. The original question was: "How can I click the button". This is the answer.

Comment: Aha! That would make total sense.

Comment: Done! Thx @Adam

Comment: @bolambert: if this answer is helpful, please mark as solved. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

A simply CSS attribute selector will do of `[title='Log in']`. The `[]` is for attribute.  Inside is the attribute = value combination.

The selector is applied via the `.querySelector` method of `document`

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Log in']").Click
```